# Swift 2 NSMutableArray() value don't shows in variable

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, swift2

Swift 2 NSMutableArray() value don't shows in variable
My codes here.

```
   var detail_desc : NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()
```

when i added this code gives me

```
 label.text = self.detail_desc.description
```

And my array output

```
   {

{

    "cat_img" = "http://asdasd.com/asd.jpg";
    "cat_name" = Good;
    id = 45;
    "is_active" = 3;
    "last_update" = "2015-11-21 15:32:42";

    }

}
```

I want to use array item to variable ;

label.text = cat_img
label2.text = cat_name

any idea ?

Comment: Never use the `description` value for anything other than debugging. It's not meant to produce results you should ever show to a user.

Comment: yes i don't know true way :) i used for show array tree for you .

Comment: You seem to have an array of dictionaries and you want specific values from a specific dictionary. So get the desired dictionary from the array and then get the desired values from the dictionary. If you don't know how to do those things, read the Swift Programming book from Apple to learn how.

Comment: thanks maddy you are very very helped me so you don't know ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot wrong with what you have, I'll try to tackle it one by one:

**Underscore**

Underscore naming isn't common in cocoa and reads very strange.  Change `detail_desc` to `detailDesc`.

Note: There are situations in which we use the underscore, one of which is extensions on core classes.  In these cases, it is prefix - underscore - name.  ie: `my_specialFunctionOrVariable`

**NSMutableArray**

`NSArray` and `NSDictionary` classes shouldn't be used in Swift unless absolutely necessary.  They behave slightly differently, and you lose all of the type safety that makes swift so great.

**Naming**

In general, naming schemes like `label`, `label2`, and `detailDescription` are very confusing.  They don't tell me anything about what each represents.  Try something like `catImageUrlLabel`, and `catNameLabel` to be more specific.  Also, `detailDescription` could be `catInformation`

**Single Object Encapsulated In Array**

You really have a dictionary as the single object in an array, I think you should just have the dictionary reference. (unless there could be more in the future).  I'll move forward assuming there won't be.

**How it might look**

Change your variable to something like this:

```
var detailDescription: [String : AnyObject] = ...
```

Then, in your UI setting code, do something like this:

```
label.text = detailDescription["cat_img"] as? String
label2.text = detailDescription["cat_name"] as? String
```

**Modelling Objects**

Json is dirty and we prefer not to deal with it as much as possible.  Consider modeling your `Cat` json to a `Cat` object:

```
struct Cat {
    let imageUrl: String
    let name: String
    let id: Int
    // etc.
}
```

Then parse the json into this model when you receive it and pass that to your view controller.

Then our code might look like this:

```
nameLabel.text = cat.name
imageUrlLabel.text = cat.imageUrl
// etc.
```

This is very clear what everything represents, and will make for a more readable, and more maintainable code base.

Hope this gets you off on the right track.

Comment: TY great documentation, i think helped too many people , so i didn't find solution on web. Thanks !